# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 in AWT

Tags: java, arrays, exception, awt, indexoutofboundsexception

This is the code I have now, it compiles fine but gives me the above error when I try to run it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class GunningBot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Color color1 = new Color(195, 174, 196);

        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1075, 700);

            {
                BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
                search:
                for (int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++) {
                        if (image.getRGB(x, y) == color1.getRGB()) {
                            robot.mouseMove(x, y);
                            break search;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        robot.delay(0);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(0);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(15);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(0);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(1500);

        robot.mouseMove(510, 440); //DO THIS BOTTOM LEFT

        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseMove(500, 140);  //MOVE TO LEFT 5 PXLS
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(250);

        robot.mouseMove(500, 370); //DO THIS TOP RIGHT

        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseMove(510, 370);  //MOVE TO RIGHT 5 PXLS
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(250);

        robot.mouseMove(700, 440); //DO THIS RIGHT CORNER MOVE LEFT 5 

        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseMove(690, 440);  //MOVE TO LEFT 5 PXLS
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(250);

        robot.mouseMove(315, 370); //DO THIS LEFT CORNER MOVE RIGHT 5 

        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseMove(320, 370);  //MOVE TO RIGHT 5 PXLS
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);


    }
}
```

I have found many example fixes that go on about over extending the Array and so on but I don't use an array. So I do not understand how to fix this error for this script. Any help at all would be amazing.

The full error is:

> exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>   at GunningBot.main(GunningBot.java:39)

bufferimage uses a Raster, could this be the problem?
rectangle is just setting the rectangle of the screen to get a screenshot of.

Also I'm editing the code with Notepad++ and don't know how to set an exception without eclipse.

Comment: What does the stack trace look like?  That will tell you what is raising the exception.  Most likely the BufferedImage or Rectangle uses an array internally, and one of your calls like `image.getRGB(x,y)` or `robot.mouseMove(x,y)` is causing it... but it would save a lot of time if you could just, you know, tell us.

Comment: Could you clean up your code a little bit? You have extra braces and the weird spacing makes it very hard to read. I also suspect the reason you are getting a array index out of bounds exception may be due to scope issues.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in these lines:

```
robot.delay(0);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here and would need to see the `Robot` class to know what this method is actually supposed to do. But since it's an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, try changing the argument to a non-zero value. For example, try this:

```
robot.delay(1);
```

Even if this solves your problem, it still wouldn't be the 'right' way to do things because you need to be aware of what this method expects and what it is supposed to do so that you can pass the argument accordingly. If this doesn't solve your problem, show us the code for the `Robot` class.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the full answer, but when I get this or similar exceptions (using eclipse) I set a breakpoint on the [exception](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-addexception_viewaction.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You say that the complete exception stacktrace is:

> exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at GunningBot.main(GunningBot.java:39)

However, line 39 of the source code that you provided is:

```
    robot.delay(0);
```

which is not an array access/update and therefore **cannot** throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  (The called method could throw the exception, but then the stacktrace would look different.)  In fact, there are no array accesses / updates **at all** in the version of "GunningBot.java" in your question.

What does this mean?

It means one of the following:

- this is not the real code, or
- this is not the real (complete) stacktrace, or
- you are not really running the code that you think you are; e.g. you forgot to recompile, or your execution and build classpaths are different.

The bottom line is that if your Question is inaccurate, you won't get decent Answers.